# Using try-catch to write unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

Can I use a try-catch to write unit tests for below code?

```
if (currentAZ == null) {               
   throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot fetch Current AZ information.");         
}
```

Comment: why would you need a try catch to test that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with Junit4 something like:

```
    @org.junit.Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testMethod() {
        try {
            callMethod(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(e).hasMessageContaining("AZ information");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

But better use Junit5:

```
    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void testMethod() {
        org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> callMethod(null)).isInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class)
                .hasMessageContaining("AZ information");
    }
```

Comment: what is the use of the try catch there? It's better to use Rules instead of polluting your testcode